# Can time really slow down due to earth revolution?

Tags: realism, arrowverse, supergirl

From **The Elseworlds** episode 3 *(Supergirl season 4 episode 9)*,

When **Evil Superman** *(Dr. Deegan)* regained **The Book of Destiny** and started to rewrite reality *(@26:13 min)*, **Flash** *(Barry Allen)* suggested  slowing down time by running around the globe in opposite direction @*just over Mach 7 speed* to create centrifugal force that'll slow down earth and everything else.

So my question is: is it really possible to do such thing in reality in the given circumstance or is it just another science fiction element for entertainment purposes? Is it scientifically possible or is it just a theory?

Comment: To be fair, it worked in Superman. If anything, it should have worked doubly well.

Comment: No, my point was if something on earth reaches at such speed, will time slow down in reality? Reference of Superman and this episode belongs to fiction.

Comment: Well, subjective time will slow down. Astronauts orbiting earth in the ISS age slower than us - by some milliseconds per year. Reversing time would - on paper - require to go faster than light. But that has relies on the same logic as a negativ meter or the square root of minus one.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> If Supergirl and I travel around the globe in opposite directions at just over mach 7, we should be able to create enough centrifugal force to slow the Earth's rotation.

---

> Is it really possible to do such thing in reality

## No. It's completely ridiculous.

Physics doesn't work that way, nor does space-time.

Indeed, the speed they mention "Mach 7" is ridiculously slow. Escape velocity (say for Apollo or the Space Shuttle) is Mach 33!

> While this is a rather nice tribute to Superman: The Movie and the scene where Superman reverses time by spinning the planet backwards, the **physics of what Barry suggests are completely nonsensical** within the stated limits. While mass does increase with velocity (per Einstein's theory of special relativity) Mach 7 is nowhere near fast enough for two human bodies to influence a mass the size of the Earth. While gravity has been shown to alter the flow of time (read up on the "Hafele–Keating experiment" for the details) Kara and Barry can't come close to generating that level of power at that low a speed.
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://screenrant.com/elseworlds-arrowverse-crossover-unanswered-questions/)</sup>

Basically, this is a call-back to the *Superman* where he did exactly the same **impossible** thing.

Comment: If they actually managed to slow down the rotation of the Earth, that would affect *solar* time (the sun would move across the sky slower, and a full rotation of the earth would take more than the usual ~24 hours). However, the inhabitants of Earth would still be experiencing time at the same rate as usual (so, lots of comments about how this day is "really seeming to drag on forever", and wondering why the sun is still up at 7PM, when it was supposed to set at 5:30). However, if this is a magical thing, it's at least possible that this change would have an effect on a spell.

Comment: @RDFozz It's much worse than that. [Earth bulges in the middle](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Equatorial_bulge). The surface is 21km "higher" at the equator than at the poles. Its rotation keeps the Earth's oceans and air "uphill". If the rotation were to slow all that water and air would settle at the poles. We'd have a strip of dry land at the middle latitudes between a polar ocean and a high desert with air too thin to breathe. Loss of the Coriolis effect and the longer days and nights would make weather go crazy. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tx_pawMRPAY Don't let super heroes geoengineer.

Comment: @Schwern - Of course, when discussing a man who can run several times the speed of sound, and an alien woman who is a living solar battery with an array of amazing powers, strict adherence to reality is out the window.

Comment: @RDFozz We have willing suspension of disbelief regarding the basic premise of any SF/fantasy. The question is where the fiction ends. Car engines in the Arrowverse seem to obey the normal laws of physics and chemistry (actually, the TV laws -- they still explode in unrealistic ways).

Comment: @Barmar - Agreed. Let me know I haven't seen the episode in question yet - that's why I made a passing reference to magic. In magical terms, the elements are earth, air, fire and water, as opposed to hydrogen, helium, etc. I can tell that this does tie into the very super-speed that we're suspending our disbelief about. The show tries to make things at least seem semi-scientific to the average viewer. This may be a case where they tried to make it seem scientifically plausible too hard, generating the opposite effect. Or, we may be too knowledgeable to accept the handwaving.

Comment: @RDFozz For an example of what Barmar said, the "Superman flies around the Earth making it rotate backwards to turn back time" breaks a lot of reality. "Superman flies around the Earth so far he goes back in time and perceives the Earth rotating backwards" only breaks one thing; flying really fast makes you go back in time. An inconsistent world invites writing characters out of jams with overpowered magic like time travel. Used sparingly it can be an awesome surprise like the scene in Superman. Used too much and you get Superman's eye beams fixing the Great Wall in Superman IV.

Comment: I appreciate that you guys help me understand how this misconception is made to make entertainment, even though it's bad because this TV source has my respect for showing the things that are scientifically possible and not just showing myths and misconceptions around. And now it's completely loosing it !

Comment: @Paulie_D: No, superman didn't do the same thing. It's a common misunderstanding of that scene. He is not rotating earth backwards to turn back time. It just looks like it's rotating backwards while superman is travelling back in time. But probably the writers of Flash also misunderstood it.

Comment: "the physics of what Barry suggests are completely nonsensical" - based on my experience, that's not limited to this specific case

Comment: @JeelVankhede I don't think the show has really been showing "scientifically possible" things. Even if we let aside the basic premise, the "science" exhibited is usually TV science that only works on screen, not in real life. I still cringe over the scene in the first season of Flash, where through "science" they extracted an *image* imprinted on a *mirror* for over a decade. It wasn't even a single image but a *series of them*.Then *did a 3D projection of them overlaid on the room*. We can do some of those things, partially but the whole thing was ridiculous.

Comment: I am pretty sure no spacecraft ever used by manking at the time of this comment ever reached mach 33. They instead keep using acceleration from the rockets to gain on the gravity well. Escape velocity is one fast enough to not need continuous acceleration.

Comment: Well, just this year a [30 ton asteroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_LA) flew around earth, impacting the atmosphere at around Mach 50, subsequently crashing into Botswana with an energy of around 0.4kt.  I don't think anyone needed to adjust their clocks.

Comment: @Mindwin Mach 33 relative to what? There's a reason we talk about delta-V when talking about orbital mechanics. Anyway, applying all the velocity at the point of launch is cheaper than accelerating over time (ignoring air resistance and structural constraints, of course) - that's why we use the highest accelerations that are practical, rather than using the lowest possible.

Comment: Even if they had enough mass and could go fast enough to affect the Earth's rotation, would  _centrifugal_ force wouldn't have anything to do with it?

Comment: Please can we not discuss *actual* physics / nitpicks when the whole premise is scientifically redonkulous.

Comment: @Luaan the rockets still burn all the way up.

Comment: @Chris In the movie, they get it exactly right at first but then flub it up at the end - Superman is traveling around the earth roughly equatorially at around 4Hz, but if you measure his actual distance from the center of the Earth it's close to 16,000 miles, meaning a circumference of around 50,000 miles or 200,000 miles per second.  That is FTL and thus time travel.  But then when he is done he stops to turn around and has to fly back the other way *at the same rate* before the Earth resumes rotating in the correct rotation, which makes no sense in this context!

Comment: @Chris Also, I don't even want to calculate how many gs he would have been pulling in *either* case.  If he was just traveling faster than light it would have been totally impractical to constantly accelerate to maintain a circle for many reasons, he should have just flown straight away from the Earth and then right back.

Comment: @Michael: I didn't say that it makes sense. Btw this was already discussed [on SciFi SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24116/how-did-superman-turn-back-time-in-the-first-movie).

Comment: @Chris Unfortunately I can't participate on that stack any more, but I do see that they have failed to note that, according to the actual on-screen depiction, Superman measurably *does* travel faster than light.

Answer (score 5):

Well, something the size of a human moving at Mach 7 (or 700) would have approximately zero effect on the rotation of the Earth.

Stopping the rotation of the Earth would again have approximately zero effect on how fast time was passing on Earth in relationship to the rest of the universe. Some effect, yes, enough to matter? No.

Different relative speeds result in time passing at different rates , but any speed difference that isn’t best described as a significant fraction of the speed of light, is only of academic interest.

Answer (score 3):

What the fictional stories ignores is that the rotation of the earth has more to do with **how we measure time** (1 rotation = 1 day), and not how space-time is involved.